# How to drop a temporary postgresql table in Talend?

Tags: postgresql, etl, talend

I am implementing ETL job using talend and in the middle of the ETL i want to drop my temporary postgresql table. Which talend component i can use for it?

Comment: Did you created the temp table through ETL jobs? Kindly elaborate more. If possible provide sample job design

Comment: yes i have created those temporary tables through ETL job using tPostgreSqlOutput component.

Comment: Then you can use `tPostgreSQLRow` component to drop the table. Write `DROP TABLE tablename;` in that component.

Comment: Thank you.it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **tPostgreSQLRow** component and able to drop my temp table